# Embedding Cordova WebView call native method

Tags: android, cordova

I have just added a Embedding Cordova WebView in my native radio stream player app, and thats works perfekt.

But now I want to change to a native view (ViewFlipper) from my javascript by calling a native function, how can I do this? ..

Please help, I have googled for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i got it to work!!!

I had to make a cordova plugin, and call the native function that way...

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("radio")) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Button click
                //cordova.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.playButton).performClick();

                // Method call
                ((RadioApp) cordova.getActivity()).setViewFlipper(0);
                ((RadioApp) cordova.getActivity()).startStream();

                // TODO: Not in use yet!
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```